# MATLAB: image horizontal/vertical autocorrelation with corr2()

Tags: matlab, image-processing, correlation

I have an image, and I'm trying to calculate both horizontal and vertical autocorrelation function estimates for `R_h[x], R_v[x], -50<=x<=50`. I've heard I can use `corr2()` to accomplish this, but I'm not sure how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with a combination of [`circshift`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/circshift.html) (to offset your image by certain ammount) and `corr2` to calculate the correlation between the original image and the offset one. You just need to loop over the values you want to check. For example:

```
img = peaks(100);  % Sample data
x = -50:50;   % Desired offsets
output = zeros(1,101); %preallocate space for the result

for i=x   % loop over the offsets
    img2=circshift(img,[i 0]);   % Shift the image by the desired lag
    output(i+51)=corr2(img,img2);   % Calculate the correlation between the offset image and the original
end

plot(x,output)
```

[image]

I think you can take it from here and get the same graph for the other dimension, or even get a matrix for a combination of shifts in the horizontal and vertical dimensions.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look at [`corr2()` documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/corr2.html).
Basically this will do:

```
mInputImage1 = randn([200, 200]);
mInputImage2 = medfilt2(randn([200, 200]));

mCorrImage = corr2(mInputImage1, mInputImage2);
```

Comment: Thanks, but this is a little different from what I'm trying to do. I'd like to scan the image vertically and plot a graph of the autocorrelation with lags ranging from -50:50, then do the same horizontally. So since the image is likely to have similar pixels within the same neighborhood I would expect a triangular looking function as the lag approaches zero from both sides. I tried looking at the documentation, but didn't find it helpful for this.

Comment: You can always extract the data you want from the total correlation function.